# Rails Ajax Jquery Delete Submits a Post request after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am trying to delete an instance of my Rails model with Ajax.

It happens on the click of a button and my code is as shown below:

```
$("#button").click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/slot_allocations/" + slotallocation_id,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"_method":"delete"},
        complete: function(){
            $( "#SlotAllocationForm" ).dialog( "close" );
            alert("Deleted successfully");
        }
    });
});
```

I am able to delete it successfully, however the `delete` method is always followed up by a `post` request to the server to create a new model with the existing data. These are the requests to the server.

```
1. POST http://localhost:3000/slot_allocations/1009 [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content  57ms]    
2. POST http://localhost:3000/slot_allocations [HTTP/1.1 302 Found  111ms]
3. GET http://localhost:3000/slot_allocations/1010 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK  185ms]
```

`#1` happens on the click of my button. However, I am not too sure why `#2` and `#3` occur.

There are two buttons in the view:

```
<button id="button">Delete</button>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the part of your view where the button is defined (and the surrounding form if applicable)

Comment: There are 2 buttons on the view <button id = "button">Delete</button> and <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>. The following code is for the first button.

Comment: I thought the submit button might be the problem and tried removing it but the 2nd post action still occurred.

Comment: For some background info on the line `data: {"_method":"delete"},` see [How do forms with PATCH, PUT, or DELETE methods work?](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch,-put,-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) -- *The Rails framework encourages RESTful design of your applications... However, most browsers don't support methods other than `GET` and `POST` when it comes to submitting forms. Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over `POST` with a hidden input named `_method`, which is set to reflect the desired method*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming your button is inside of a form, clicking it is probably submitting that form in addition to firing the ajax request.

What you want to do is prevent the default action of clicking the button, which is submitting the form.

Change the `function()` parameter to `function(event)`, then add an `event.preventDefault()` call:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/slot_allocations/" + slotallocation_id,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"_method":"delete"},
        complete: function(){
            $( "#SlotAllocationForm" ).dialog( "close" );
            alert("Deleted successfully");
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You saved my life with the `data: {"_method": "delete"},...` part. +1'd!

Comment: @cassi.lup `data: {"_method":"delete"}` was in the OP's question. Your +1 should have gone to @butter-beer -- just say'n.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
type: "DELETE"
```

instead of:

```
type: "POST"
```

and remove

```
data: {"_method":"delete"}
```

Comment: [most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch,-put,-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark); for another reference, see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and search for *Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are **not** supported by all browsers.*

Comment: Today's browsers support `PUT`/`DELETE` while making `XMLHTTP ` requests. However it may not support in <form> tag

Comment: In my case type: POST with data: {"_method":"delete"} is just what i needed. When I used DELETE what happened is it run: DELETE "/controller/member_id" and deleted the object with member_id but then it started another request: DELETE "/controller" and that raised a No route error. It was a link not a button however it was in a form. I don't know what caused this anomaly.